# Js - solving challenge Range Sum Query - Immutable with creating object and its properties

Tags: javascript, object-create

I was going through the problems on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-query-immutable/description/) site, and saw a problem that I don't know how to approach. This is how they explain it:

> Given an integer array nums, find the sum of the elements between
>   indices i and j (i ≤ j), inclusive.
>
> Example: Given nums = [-2, 0, 3, -5, 2, -1]
>
> sumRange(0, 2) -> 1 sumRange(2, 5) -> -1 sumRange(0, 5) -> -3 Note:
>   You may assume that the array does not change. There are many calls to
>   sumRange function.

And this is the code:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 */
var NumArray = function(nums) {
   this.nums = nums;
};

/** 
 * @param {number} i 
 * @param {number} j
 * @return {number}
 */
NumArray.prototype.sumRange = function(i, j) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (i; i <= j; i++) {
        sum += this[i];
    }
    return sum;
};

/** 
 * Your NumArray object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * var obj = Object.create(NumArray).createNew(nums)
 * var param_1 = obj.sumRange(i,j)
 */
```

What I don't know how to do is, or what exactly it means is this part:

```
var obj = Object.create(NumArray).createNew(nums)
```

Am I suppose to create a property createNew that takes mums and creats and array, and why should I do that if the nums are already sent as an array?

Comment: My guess is that they messed up and meant `var obj = new NumArray(nums)`.

Comment: Can you state the full purpose of the exercise attached to this code?

Comment: I have added their explanation of the task

Comment: Do you still need a solution for this problem? Have you already tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what exactly it means is this part:
>
> ```
> var obj = Object.create(NumArray).createNew(nums)
> ```

They messed it up and meant simply `var obj = new NumArray(nums)` (which still is unnecessarily complicated for a functional language like JS).

Apparently the description was changed at some point by someone clueless, as all the old JavaScript submissions in the discussion section (e.g. [this one](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/46515/javascript-solution)) have the correct code in the comment.

Comment: Thank you for noticing this.